# Entity Framework 4, free Oracle provider?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, oracle11g

Can i user ODAC or another free provider in EF4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ODP.NET doesn't currently support Entity Framework, and as far as I know the only available EF providers for Oracle are not free (DevArt, DataDirect...).

However, in June [Oracle announced](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/oracle-entity-framework-sod-130214.pdf) that they were working to add EF support to ODP.NET. The roadmap says they will have a beta by the end of 2010, and a final version in 2011.

Comment: By the way, the answer is Yes. It's free.

Comment: Check the link [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework/) EF 6 for oracle since 2015 only

Answer (score -1):

ODAC isn't free. Try provider from this vendor - http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/. I nave baught it, but I know that they have an Express edition with some limitations. Try to read more about this product.

Comment: Both the release ODAC and the beta for EF are free: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html